# Null Pointer Exception setting layout Params of custom imageView in NavigationDrawerMenu

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android-imageview

Hi Im trying to set Layour Params of a Custom ImageView class (called MLRoundedImageView) in navigation Drawer menu but always i have the same error:

```
 03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3187)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3170)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at com.norriors.java.mtbfreeride.Controllers.PersonalDrawerAdapter.getView(PersonalDrawerAdapter.java:59)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:733)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1622)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2102)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:931)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:502)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1866)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1687)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-26 19:27:13.446: E/AndroidRuntime(6532):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here is my class

```
package com.norriors.java.mtbfreeride.Controllers;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.norriors.java.mtbfreeride.R;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Classe PersonalDrawerAdapter
 */
public class PersonalDrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DrawerItems> {

    Context context;
    List<DrawerItems> drawerItemsList;
    int layoutResID;
    DrawerItems dItem;

    public PersonalDrawerAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceID,
                                 List<DrawerItems> listItems) {
        super(context, layoutResourceID, listItems);
        this.context = context;
        this.drawerItemsList = listItems;
        this.layoutResID = layoutResourceID;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        DrawerItemHolder drawerHolder;
        View view = convertView;

        dItem = this.drawerItemsList.get(position);
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            drawerHolder = new DrawerItemHolder();

            view = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, parent, false);
            drawerHolder.ItemName = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.drawer_itemName);


            drawerHolder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerTitle);

            drawerHolder.headerLayout = (LinearLayout) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.headerLayout);
            drawerHolder.itemLayout = (LinearLayout) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.itemLayout);

            drawerHolder.icon = dItem.getImgUser();

            drawerHolder.headerLayout.addView(drawerHolder.icon);
            drawerHolder.icon.getLayoutParams().width = 50;
            drawerHolder.icon.getLayoutParams().height = 50;

            view.setTag(drawerHolder);

        } else {
            drawerHolder = (DrawerItemHolder) view.getTag();
        }


        if (dItem.getTitle() != null) {
            drawerHolder.headerLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
            drawerHolder.title.setText(dItem.getTitle());

        } else {

            drawerHolder.itemLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);

            drawerHolder.ItemName.setText(dItem.getItemName());
        }

        return view;
    }

    private static class DrawerItemHolder {
        TextView ItemName, title;
        MLRoundedImageView icon;
        LinearLayout headerLayout, itemLayout;
    }


}
```

And my view.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/drawerTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#DADADC" ></View>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/drawer_itemName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:background="#DADADC"
            ></View>
    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

To be honest i dont know what is happens, because i add the view before set the width and height. Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: which line is 59 in your adapter? That's the line where the error occurs. Check whether view is inflated and `headerLayout!=null`

Comment: Well the problem was that all the time the fragment refresh himself and then lost the object.

I dont know why but  at least i can solve with one if with two clauses: if (headerLayout != null && icon != null)

Thanks for your help.